# Display_name in menu

Tags: menus

I'm trying to display the "Display_name" of an user in the menu. So I created a menu item called "#profile_name#".

It's working when i'm logged, but it displays "**Untitled**" when i'm not logged. Do you know why ?

```
   function give_profile_name(){
        $user=wp_get_current_user();
        $name=$user->display_name; 
        return $name;
    }

    add_shortcode('profile_name', 'give_profile_name');

    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_dynamic_menu_items' );
    function my_dynamic_menu_items( $menu_items ) {
        foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
            if ( '#profile_name#' == $menu_item->title ) {
                global $shortcode_tags;
                if ( isset( $shortcode_tags['profile_name'] ) ) {
                    // Or do_shortcode(), if you must.
                    $menu_item->title = call_user_func( $shortcode_tags['profile_name'] );
                }    
            }
        }

        return $menu_items;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Because if you are not logged wp_get_current_user() doesn't have a username, what do you want to show if the user is not logged in? And what do you want to show when the user is logged the username how is logged?

Comment: I just want display the "Display_name" when user is logged in and display nothing when the user is not logged in. :)

Comment: Good, check my answer.

Comment: Why are you using a shortcode here? Seems like overkill - all you need is `if ( '#profile_name#' == $menu_item->title ) { $menu_item->title = give_profile_name(); }`

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if the user is logged in, doing `is_user_logged_in()`, if so you get the username.

```
function give_profile_name(){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user=wp_get_current_user();
        $name=$user->display_name; 
        return $name;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

You can also change your if to check if the shortcode is returning **Untitled**.

```
if ( isset( $shortcode_tags['profile_name'] ) && $shortcode_tags['profile_name'] != "Untitled")
```

Comment: Hello Castiblanco, thank you, but it displays me "Untitled" when I'm not logged in.

Comment: Try this new code, returning an empty string "" if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Hum, still "Untitled", sorry

Comment: Hmm sounds like a cache problem or something, if you are returning something I cannot say the same.

Comment: If I write for example "return "duh";" it's working. It seems doesn't accept empty string.

Comment: Ok, check it again, we can check within the second if of my_dynamic_menu_items if the return value is different that untitled.

Comment: If the menu item has no name (eg, if the page is untitled) then WP's `wp_nav_menu()` prints "Untitled" automatically.